# Find all functions satisfying the condition $f(x+y)+f(x)f(y)=f(xy)+f(x)+f(y)$

Tags: functional-equations

Find all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to{\mathbb{R}}$ such that

$f(x+y)+f(x)f(y)=f(xy)+f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y\in{\mathbb{R}}$

first I put $x=y=0$ so I got $f(0)=0$ or $f(0)=2$.

For the case $f(0)=2$, putting $y=0$, I got $f(x)=2$ for all real $x$.

For the case $f(0)=0$ I am not able to proceed. Pre-calculus method is preferred.

Comment: For the case $f(0) = 0$: Try $y=-x$. This will give you additional conditions

Comment: @michael I tried that but it didn't give useful condition.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I made an error in reasoning

Comment: You can also put $x=y=2$ to find two values for $f(2)$

Answer (score 0):

Set $y = 1$ and you can get $f(x+1)$ expressed in terms of $f(x)$, therefore if you know $f(1)$ you know $f(n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

As a few people already mentioned set $y=-x$ and you get $f(-n)$ in terms of $f(n)$ and $f(n^2)$, hence $f(1)$ determines $f(n)$ for all $n\in \mathbb Z$.

I don't see the way to go from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb R$. I think you need to assume continuity at some point to get the final answer.

Comment: To find some values in $\mathbb{Q}$ it is possible to force $x+y=xy$ so that $y=\frac{x}{x-1}$ and $f(\frac{x}{x-1})=\frac{f(x)}{f(x)-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

I claim that the only solutions of the functional equation
$$f(x+y)+f(x)f(y)=f(xy)+f(x)+f(y)\tag0\label0$$
are the identity function $f(x)=x$ and the constant functions $f(x)=0$ and $f(x)=2$. To show that, let $y=1$ in \eqref{0} and you'll get:
$$f(x+1)=\big(2-f(1)\big)f(x)+f(1)\tag1\label1$$
Substituting $x+1$ for $x$ in \eqref{1} we have:
$$f(x+2)=\big(2-f(1)\big)^2f(x)+3f(1)-f(1)^2$$
Letting $x=1$ in \eqref{1} we know that $f(2)=3f(1)-f(1)^2$, so using the last equation we get:
$$f(x+2)=\big(2-f(1)\big)^2f(x)+f(2)\tag2\label2$$
Now we can let $y=2$ in \eqref{0} and have:
$$f(2x)=f(x+2)-f(2)+\big(f(2)-1\big)f(x)$$
Thus knowing $f(2)=3f(1)-f(1)^2$ and using \eqref{2} we get:
$$f(2x)=\big(3-f(1)\big)f(x)\tag3\label3$$
Now, substituting $2x$ for $x$ and $2y$ for $y$ in \eqref{0}, and using \eqref{3} we find out that:
$$\big(3-f(1)\big)\Big(f(x+y)-f(x)-f(y)-\big(3-f(1)\big)\big(f(xy)-f(x)f(y)\big)\Big)=0$$
But by \eqref{0} we know that $f(x+y)-f(x)-f(y)=f(xy)-f(x)f(y)$ and thus:
$$\big(3-f(1)\big)\big(f(1)-2\big)\big(f(xy)-f(x)f(y)\big)=0\tag4\label4$$
If $f(1)=3$ then by \eqref{3} we must have $f(1)=0$ which leads to a contradiction, so this case doesn't happen. If $f(1)=2$ then by \eqref{1} we find out that $f$ is the constant function $f(x)=2$. Otherwise, by \eqref{4} we have $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$ and hence by \eqref{0}, $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$. It's well known that in this case $f$ is the identity function $f(x)=x$ or the constant function $f(x)=0$. For example, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/684078/functional-equations-fxy-fx-fy-and-fxy-fxfy) for a proof.

Comment: I flagged the question as a duplicate of [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481673/gxygxgy-gxygxgy-for-all-x-y). But as it was (surprisingly!) declined, I posted an answer, which is a bit different from all the answers there, but similar to the answer of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1556402/functional-equation-fxy-fx-fy-alphafxy-fxfy-is-solvable-withou).